# ExtJS: Automatically resize form fields on window resize

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've created Ext.Window with some Ext.form fields inside. But when I resize window form elements still have initial width and height.

Is it required explicitly resize form fields on window resize? Or there is some option that enables auto resize of form fields?

Sample code:

```
var f_1 = new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel: 'Label 1'});
var f_2 = new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel: 'Label 2'});
var fp = new Ext.form.FormPanel({items: [f_1, f_2]});

var w = new Ext.Window({
    layout: 'form',
    title: 'test',
    items: fp
});

w.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check out anchoring, which makes for nicely-resizable forms:

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/anchoring.html

See the "anchor" property on "Component":

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Component

Answer (score 1):

```
var f_1 = new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel: 'Label 1', anchor:'95%'});
```

would do it. you can see some samples [there](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/dynamic.js) and the documentation [there](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.AnchorLayout).

Also if you don't want to specify size for each of them you can push the default from the form panel with the `defaults` config object

```
var fp = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
           items: [f_1, f_2]
           ,defaults: {
               anchor: '95%' 
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the FormPanel "fp" is partially at fault.

In Ext JS, it is usually best practice to declare everything from the window all the way down inside the Ext.Window constructor. Creating things and trying to attach them later has been the source of much frustration for me.

(Ok, the other answer about width: 100% is likely better. But still, I've had a lot of problems with resizing, etc. when not declaring everything at once... haven't figured out exactly when it's ok to do so yet.)

Comment: @richard: I have no problem with that ... so I don't really understand what you are talking about ...

Comment: @RageZ: Looks like your problem is solved in this case, but I left my answer up because I've seen layout wonkiness numerous times in Ext JS when I've created a control and referenced it in the Items of the layout parent rather than declaring it there there. Not the right answer for you, but could be for someone else who runs across this question with a similar issue unrelated to anchor/width.